# Substring - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a string that get's inserted into a table. The size and content of the string varies.

I basically want all characters between two known words (`_ Part1ID =` and `_ Part2ID =`).

I want to get everything in between these two strings from the whole string.

I have tried [this approach](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/41388/query-to-select-a-string-between-two-known-strings.html) but getting everything before `_ Part2ID =`.

Anyone know how to make this work in given conditions?

Thank you

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for.  Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Whilst you're adding examples might Part1 and/or Part2 appear *multiple* times in the input? If so, how should that be handled?

Comment: Thank you guys for many responses. Mark's answer seems to work for my situation. I will post an example soon to see if there is any better technique to do it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
with a as
(select 'abc_ Part1ID =efg_ Part2ID =jkl' a)
select a,
       substring(a,
                 charindex('_ Part1ID =',a)+len('_ Part1ID ='),
                 charindex('_ Part2ID =',a)-charindex('_ Part1ID =',a)-len('_ Part1ID ='))
from a
```

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @someString nvarchar(200) = 'lkasjdlkasjdl_Part1ID=hereIsTheBitYouWant_Part2IDlksajdlaksdj'

select  substring(@someString, patindex('%_Part1ID%', @someString) + 9, patindex('%_Part2ID%', @someString) - (patindex('%_Part1ID%', @someString) + 9))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @s varchar(1000)
SET @s = 'this is a test _ Part1ID = of the emergency broadcast _ Part2ID = system'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, PATINDEX('%_ Part1ID =%',@s)+11,
            PATINDEX('%_ Part2ID =%',@s)-PATINDEX('%_ Part1ID =%',@s)-11)
```

Comment: Including some explanation can be useful to help to OP understand the substance of the code you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

Modify this template with your keywords and field names.

```
declare @mystring nvarchar(max) = 'some irrelevant text STARTPOINTI Should Return this text to youENDPOINT other irrelevant text';
declare @bookend1 nvarchar(max) = 'STARTPOINT';
declare @bookend2 nvarchar(max) = 'ENDPOINT';
select
  substring
   (
    @mystring
   ,CHARINDEX(@bookend1,@mystring) + len(@bookend1)
   ,charindex(@bookend2,@mystring) - charindex(@bookend1,@mystring) - len(@bookend1)
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

say the string (or string column) were named `s`, try:

```
substring(s, nullif(charindex('_ Part1ID = ', s),0) + 12   -- skip tag (length = 12)
           , nullif(charindex('_ Part2ID = ', s),0)
             - (nullif(charindex('_ Part1ID = ', s),0) + 12) )
```

This assumes that the Part2ID tag will never appear before Part1ID.  We do `nullif(charindex(...),0)` so that the result will rightly be null if we don't find the tag.

If you were to create an inline function, you could be a bit more elegant:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetPart ( 
    @s varchar(8000), @tag1 varchar(20), @tag2 varchar(20)
) returns varchar(100) AS
BEGIN
    return (    select substring(@s, i1, i2 - i1)
        from (  select i1, i2 = nullif(charindex(@tag2, @s, i1),0)    -- ', i1' ensures we look after @tag1
            from (select i1 = nullif(charindex(@tag1, @s),0) + len(@tag1)) t ) t )
END
```